# Sqoop error in direct mode

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop

I am trying to import data from Memsql to HDFS using Sqoop in direct mode.
My Sqoop command follows this way

```
sqoop import -D mapred.task.timeout=0 --connect jdbc:mysql://XXXXXXX:3306/dbname --username XXXX --password XXXX  --table catalog_returns --target-dir XXXXXX  --direct
```

I am able to migrate data without direct mode. However, using direct mode produces the following error

> Error: java.io.IOException: mysqldump terminated with status 2
>           at 
>           org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.MySQLDumpMapper.map(MySQLDumpMapper.java:486)
>           at 
>           org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.MySQLDumpMapper.map(MySQLDumpMapper.java:49)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)

It will be a great help, if someone can provide their solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I formatted your code and the error message to improve readability.  Sorry the direct mode is failing.  Consider if the reviewers would benefit from seeing the successful migration code too.

Comment: Include --verbose and paste the error stack.

Comment: Error: java.io.IOException: mysqldump terminated with status 2
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.MySQLDumpMapper.map(MySQLDumpMapper.java:486

Comment: Refer: https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.7/SqoopUserGuide.html#_supported_databases

memsql and mysql are different. Mysql supports --direct as per sqoop documentation.